# php trying to return the number of rows in a sql table

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Trying to return the total row count for a sql table. My code returns the number of rows that are added not the total number of rows in the table. Any suggestions?

PHP:

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $query = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES ('$email')");
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
    echo $count;
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
exit;
```

Comment: I am using MAMP with PHP 5.2.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`rowCount()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) ist not a direct method of the PDO class, it is a method from [`PDOStatement`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php).

Syntax:

```
public int PDOStatement::rowCount ( void )
```

Example based on your approach:

```
try {
    $query = $db->prepare("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES ('$email')");
    $query->execute();
    $count = $query->rowCount();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    ...
```

Comment: So your code works. However, its not what I was looking for exactly. I have edited my post to reflect the changes. 

But what I was intending to do was to return the total number of rows in the table, not just the number of rows that I changed. My PDO object that I create in my database.php file is $db. Would it be easier to do a sql count function instead?

Comment: I now understand that I have been attempting my intended solution with the wrong method.

Comment: @RyanSalmons Exactly. If you want to determine that, you have to `SELECT` it after you have updated your records, for example with a `COUNT` in it. Your `UPDATE`/`REPLACE`-statements will only return you the affected rows. It might look like this: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM launch_email WHERE yourfield = "somevalue";`

Answer (score 0):

**[PDO::exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.exec.php)** returns the number of affected rows.

So you don't need to use `rwoCount()`, and note `rowCount()` is the method from `PDOStatement`.

```
require(ROOT_PATH . "inc/database.php");
try {
    $count = $db->exec("REPLACE INTO launch_email VALUES ('$email')");
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Data could not be submitted to the database.";
    exit;
}
```